# STAR error - INPUT file error: could not open read file: Read1

Tags: bash, rna-seq

I am trying to run STAR alignment for pair-end reads and keep getting this error:
"EXITING: because of fatal INPUT file error: could not open read file: Read1.
I can't find where is the problem in my syntax. Here is my code:

```sh
cd /cs/labs/michall/yaelh/Projects/dsRNA-seq

# Mapping to masked genome:
STAR --runThreadN 6  \
     --runMode alignReads \
     --readFilesCommand gunzip -c \
     --genomeDir /Star_indices/Nve_genome_masked_index \     
     --readFilesIn  /output_files/Trimmomatic_out_paired/ad1_IgG_S10_R1_001_Trimmo_out_paired.fastq.gz  \
                    /output_files/Trimmomatic_out_paired/ad1_IgG_S10_R3_001_Trimmo_out_paired.fastq.gz  \       
     --outFileNamePrefix /Star_results/ad1_IgG_S10_R1_ \
     --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
     --outSAMunmapped Within \
     --outSAMattributes Standard \
     --quantMode TrancriptomSam GeneCount
```

Comment: Is the genomeDir `/cs/labs/michall/yaelh/Projects/dsRNA-seq/Star_indices/Nve_genome_masked_index` or `/Star_indices/Nve_genome_masked_index`?

Comment: The option `--readFilesCommand gunzip -c` may also have to be replaced by `--readFilesCommand 'gunzip -c'` but I'm not sure, as I don't know the STAR command

Comment: The full path to the index file is:  /cs/labs/michall/yaelh/Projects/dsRNA-seq/Star_indices/Nve_genome_masked_index

Comment: OK, then remove all the prefixing `/` in the STAR command because they imply a full path. Example: `--genomeDir /Star_indices/Nve_genome_masked_index` has to be changed to `--genomeDir Star_indices/Nve_genome_masked_index`

Comment: according to STAR manual it's : --readFilesCommand gunzip -c (without quotation marks)

Comment: https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR/blob/master/doc/STARmanual.pdf seems to be saying that the argument to `--readFilesIn` should be a single string with a comma between the file names. (That's a horrible design, if it's true.)

Comment: I tried. It didn't help :(

Comment: a comma is used between multiple samples but not between a paired end